# Not able to figure out the meaning of the error in the LOG file

Tags: error-handling, custom-timer-job

I am getting the following error when I try to deploy my custom timer job.

" Cannot synchronize profile property languages until the ProfileDB is upgraded for UserProfileApplication 'User Profile Service".

Can anyone please explain me the meaning and cause of this error.

Due to this error I am unable to successfully deploy the Custom timer job.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this post? -  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/0ceaa53a-dfb3-481c-8916-c3fbec70b896/

It says that this could be a patch problem -
like SP1 or something. Then, after SP1 you need to have apply the latest CU for SharePoint and then you have to restart user profile sync service. It should be ok.

Comment: thx a lot for ur quick response... Hope tht this solves my problem.

Comment: Welcome and Good Luck :)

Comment: I have successfully deployed my timer job and it appears in the Central Admin but I cannot find it in Job Definitions or Running Jobs either in the Monitoring option of Central Admin. What could be the cause of this problem??

Comment: good to know that it worked. Can you post your next question as a new one? As an immediate help, I would advise you to check whether the scope of your timer job is "Web Application". Also, in Job definitions there is a 'Scheduled Jobs' section in the top. Try filtering the job definitions by selecting your web application (The web application where you have deployed) name on the right top and move through all the pages in the pagination below. You would be able to see the Timer job.

Comment: I have posted this as a new question. The scope of my timer job is Web Application. I have tried all these options that you have suggested but I donot find my timer job.